# How to export data gridview to xml

Tags: c#, parsing, xml-parsing

Hi am trying to save a data gridview to XML file using XDocument but the problem is when i click export button the data gridview gets clear and the exported XML file is empty

> This button fill datagridview from multiple textboxs :

```
 private void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

     dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = txtOne.Text;
     dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = txtTwo.Text;
     dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = txtThree.Text; 
 }
```

> This button to export as XML:

```
private void Export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
new XDeclaration("1.0", "ISO-8859-1", null),
new XElement("root",    
    dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new XElement("child", new object[]{
            new XElement("one",row[0]),
            new XElement("two",row[1]),
            new XElement("three",row[2]),
            }));


dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
doc.Save(FILENAME);
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Convert.ToString(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "File Name |*.xml";
saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    doc.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
}
```

Comment: Please, provide Minimal, Reproducible Example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Since you datasource is a datatable you can write the datatable to xml in one instruction dt.WriteXml(filename).  Instead of filling the DGV with new data add the new data to the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want read all data from `DataGridView` and export to `XDocument` you have to use two cycle for read all rows and all cells.

```cs
private void ExportButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var columnHeaders = (from DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns select column.HeaderText).ToArray();

    var xDoc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "ISO-8859-1", null),
        new XElement("root"));

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.IsNewRow)
            continue;

        var xRow = new XElement("row");

        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            xRow.Add(new XElement(columnHeaders[cell.ColumnIndex], cell.Value));
        }

        xDoc.Element("root")?.Add(xRow);
    }

    xDoc.Save(@"d:\tmp\test.xml");
}
```

If you want, you can add `saveFileDialog` and set the file name from the dialog

Comment: Is it possible to make xml schema like this

`<root>
  <row>
<one>125</one>
<two>125</two>
<child> <three>987</three> </child>
  </row>
</root>`

Comment: You can add ```if``` to two cycle and column column index or header name and do what you need (create new element with sub element or skip this column or ...)